# Highcharts export all after scrolling and specific extremes for export type

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

Have an issue while exporting data from Highcharts in react v2.1.3 ( highcharts-react-official )

My use case:
PDF export should have all data points in it ( e.g if current view shows 5 data points and on scroll there are 5 more the exported pdf should have all 10 data points )

Images ( JPEG and PNG ) should only have current view export ( Whatever is visible should be exported )

Problem:
Initial exporting options:
`chartOptions: { xAxis: [{max: undefined, min: undefined}]  // to export all }`
However this has a problem with scroll
If I export graph without scrolling the graph export has all data points but if I export after scrolling a bit the exported graph has only current visible chart

Expected: Export all event after scrolling

Current Behaviour: After scroll exports only current visible

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `exportChart` method and adapt axis extremes depending on the exporting type. For example:

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'exportChart', function(proceed, options) {
    const xAxis = this.xAxis[0];
    const extremes = xAxis.getExtremes();

    if (options && options.type === 'application/pdf') {
      xAxis.setExtremes(null, null);
    }
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    xAxis.setExtremes(extremes.min, extremes.max);
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cbmus1xg/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts